# .git-folder when cloning on github

Tags: github

I came on to a little "problem" that I can't explain myself, so I'll need your help.

When I clone a repository on my laptop, it just clones the repo and that's it.
When I clone a repository on my desktop, it clones the repo but also adds a .git-folder.

In that folder are: [.git-folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hv5N7.png)

Does anyone know what this .git-folder is and why it clones it on my desktop but not on my laptop?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It contains the repository. Are you sure its not just hidden on your laptop?

Comment: I don't really know for sure. How can I unhide/hide it?

Comment: Depends on the OS.

Comment: I'm using Windows10. But it's a general hide/show command I guess? Not just for showing/hiding this .git folder. I'll do a Google search on that myself first.